# ECR status-related question

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, passport-renewals, ecr

Will the ECR status on my Indian passport be automatically invalid after I turn 50 years old, or do I need to apply for a new passport after I get 50 to remove my ECR tag?

Answer (score 1):

ECR status of passport is indicated by a physical [stamp](https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/5FF8aee9he_MVr7Gekg5tg--~B/aD0zNTQ7dz02MzU7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/http://media.zenfs.com/en-IN/video/video.indianewzsteet.com/pas.jpg) on the passport. Absence of stamp makes your passport Non-ECR.

Though I cannot find any canonical reference, the insistence on ECR stamp in the [MEA website](http://mea.gov.in/emigration-abroad-for-emp.htm) makes it look like as long as your passport has this stamp, you will be considered an ECR person.

To remove the stamp you will have to apply for re-issue of a passport. In the reasons for reissue on the passport website, they even have a separate column for it: "Deletion of ECR"

[image: Doc Advisor on passport website]

In your case you would attach a birth certificate and your re-issued passport will not have ECR endorsment.

Please note that ECR passports are equivalent to normal passports if you are visiting abroad on a non-employment visa (Source is the quoted MEA website).

Comment: You can change your date and place of birth? How does that work? Is this just for mistakes (oops, my parents lied to me, I wasn't really born on March 5, I just found documents saying it was March 3), or is there an actual process for obtaining a new date or place of birth?

Comment: @RobertColumbia See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111362/different-date-of-birth-in-passport-matriculation-certificate-and-all-other-doc) for one such situation. In India it is common for people who were born in 1940s, and 1950s to have different dates of birth in different records simply because the systems for doing so were not so robust at that time (India had just gotten its independence). It is quite common for people (older generation) to have no birth certificate or school leaving certificate.

Comment: The system is mainly for mistakes that may have happened due to lack of documentation but in practice it is quite difficult to get it changed.